# Any AS3 solutions for video compression?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, video, ffmpeg

I've been looking around and it does not seem like it is possible with Flash, but is there any way to compress a video file from a mobile device then upload it to a server? Right now some of my videos are too large (30 mb for 15 seconds) resulting in long upload times. Everything seems to point to ffmpeg but to implement ffmpeg you have to use the NativeProcess which isn't allowed on mobile devices. Is such a thing possible on the server side via PHP or only client side? or should I switch to something like Xamarin instead of AS3.

Thanks!

Comment: You can absolutely do this with PHP or pretty much any other serverside language. You need to make sure that the php.ini settings allow for whatever max size you are going to submit (default is 50mb), and use `composer` or similar to install a compression library. You can also do this pretty easily in node.js, python, ruby, or any other backend language, and it'll crush it waaaaaaay faster than frontend will.

Comment: Awesome, the video does not have to be uploaded to the server already does it? I read somewhere that it does. Meaning I can choose a video file from my device and it will convert/compress then upload?

Comment: It does. Use ajax. If you don't know any backend languages, you will probably be the most at home with node.js, which just runs javascript. Since both actionscript and javascript are based off of EMCAscript, you should mostly be familiar with the syntax already.

Comment: You can also accomplish this with coldfusion, if you are particularly comfortable with Adobe's suite.

Comment: I would not otherwise recommend either of those if you weren't already an actionscript dev.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I can't get around the initial long upload time unless I can find a way to compress the file on the client side? Because I sent the same video through Snapchat for a comparison and they were significantly faster than my app's upload and I'm just wondering how they did it.

Comment: It's always going to be faster to do this stuff serverside. For client side code, you're competing for RAM and threads with their music, apps, fifty browser tabs, and whatever else the client is doing. Serverside resources are dedicated explicitly to stuff like this and it can throw 100% of whatever is available at it.

Comment: If you set up the backend using streams, it will start sending it and/or compressing it as soon as it has anything instead of waiting on the whole file, which is super fast and not very memory heavy at all.

Comment: Hmm, ok that makes sense. Could you point me in the right direction in doing something like that? Right now I just have the action script requesting my php file on an amazon ec2 dedicated server running wamp.

Comment: In php, ffmpeg for compression and Guzzle for streaming

Comment: use composer to install both pretty painlessly

Comment: Ok just to make sure, upload video then use ffmpeg to compress the video once it is completely uploaded and in the meantime guzzle will allow for streaming once the upload has started? What if the user closes the app during the upload process?

Comment: You'll want to install ffmpeg using `apt-get` or whatever package manager you have on your ec2 instance, then composer as per the instructions here: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: If they close it, it severs the connection and the stream closes. No big deal.

Comment: When you have composer, use:
`composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg` and `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`, then you're pretty much good to go.

Comment: streams send very small chunks of bytes at a time, so they are very efficient. That is how youtube, soundcloud, and pretty much all other media streaming works. You could theoretically stream a 20 terrabyte file with a program that only has 1mb of ram and it wouldn't make any difference, provided you have the disk space and bandwidth to handle it.

Comment: Compression will likely take the most memory on the server.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot i will get started on that

Comment: Right on, hope it works out well for you.